# How to add a SearchBar in a TableViewCell programmatically? /Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I tried to place a searchBar into the first row of my TableView Cells, but it only throws an error but I don't understand why, can someone tell me what to do? Thanks in advance!

//Custom Cell

```
class SearchCell: UITableViewCell, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    let searchbar = UISearchBar()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(searchbar)
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    func setConstraints() {
        searchbar.placeholder = "Country, City"
        searchbar.delegate = self
        searchbar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        
        //Constraints
        searchbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchbar.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        searchbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        searchbar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280).isActive = true
        searchbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }
    
   
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setConstraints()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

And this is the ViewController which contains the TableView:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
!Line 20!        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchCell") as! SearchCell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
            return cell
    }
    }

let tableView = UITableView()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        
//        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = "Search"
        
        //Functions
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    
    
    func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
        
        //Constraints
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }
        
        
        
    
}
```

I watched some tutorials etc. but they didn't help me, so thank you guys!

Comment: But what's the error? You haven't even told us that, so we don't know what you need help with.

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry.. the error is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in line 20, I marked the line twenty in code

Comment: Maybe your cell is not a SearchCell

Comment: @ChrisCode - did you set a Prototype cell in Storyboard to `SearchCell` class, and gave it a Reuse Identifier of "SearchCell"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your cell with its reuseIdentifier with your tableview first. I don't see that in the code you posted.

After `super.viewDidLoad()` add something like

`tableView.register(SearchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchCell")`

Comment: Now it throws me the following error in the AppDelegate: Thread 1: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

Comment: Makes sense. Your code says `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath); return cell` if row is not zero. So, you either have to return a default cell or also register a cell with reuseIdentifier 'Cell'. Basically, you're asking the same question again.

Comment: Oh thats logical